# How to parse JSON based on different parameters in android fragments

Tags: android

Good day, this is more of a design question.

- I have a base api class that builds from a String of received parameters and function url, parses the JSON and returns a JSONObject. This base class has a number of constructors to receive different parameters from the subclasses
- Have a number of classes that extends this Base Api class, passing in different parameters to the super class and calling in the method that parses and returns the JSON Object.
- Have fragments that contain inner classes which extends an AsyncTask where i call the subclasses and process the returned JSON object. it communicates the returned JSON Object( success or error ) to the containing Activity through the interface method.

Now my question, is this a good design process or is there a much more efficient method bearing in mind that the function url and parameters will always be fixed. (well there is no intention to change it anytime soon or at all). any other solution will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: so is this a good design or is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you don`t know what are the parameters you going to use in future you can go with JSONObjects or HashMaps. In case of HashMap use dont need to think about the keys where you do not have check for the key and do something. HashMap always returns the list of keys, so you can iterate HashMap to get the values.

Comment: Yes its a good way. But HashMap is better than using JSONObjects to modify the values or getting them or removing them.